# CP working as MV in linux + PHP + CRON

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php file which will run every 45 Minutes of an hour.In this PHP file, I am generating a CSV file and copying to some mounted directory.
    Whenever cron runs, cp command working as mv, which means source file is missing.whenever I execute that php file manually, I can see that source file existing.Here is the piece of php code which I have used to copy the file.

```
$filename = "test.csv";
$cmd = 'cp '.$filename.' /data/cdr';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: A `cp` certainly will _not_ suddenly start removing files. That must be caused by some other part of your setup. Definitely.

Comment: @Epodax Question is why source file is missing ?